# How to set the same logging format for all handlers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am using [`.setFormatter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.setFormatter) to set the same `logging.Formatter()`  on each of my handlers.

Is there a way to set a global default format?

Alternatively - is it possible to iterate though the handlers already added via `.addHandler()` to a logger ?

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757578/what-is-the-default-python-logging-formatter) mentions *what* the format is, but not how to *set* it.

Comment: Set the format on the global logger and nowhere else.

Comment: You can iterate through the list in the `handlers` attribute of a logger.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: thanks. I managed to iterate over the `handlers` in my logger. If you would not mind to turn the comment into an answer I would gladly accept it. I did not understand the first comment, though (about a "global logger" -- what is that? Do you mean the logger received via `getLogger()`? it does not have a `setFormatter()` method)

Comment: Yes, when you call it without a name. I guess it's technically called root logger, not global logger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The intended way is to attach the formatter to each handler as you're creating them.**

Since you're supposed to set up logging destinations in one, central place at the start of the main program, this isn't so taxing to do.

E.g. this is the stock logging set-up code that I use in my scripts that are to be run autonomously:

```
# set up logging #####################################
import sys,logging,logging.handlers,os.path
log_file=os.path.splitext(__file__)[0]+".log"
l = logging.getLogger()
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
f = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(process)d:%(thread)d %(name)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
h=logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
h.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
h.setFormatter(f)
l.addHandler(h)
h=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_file,maxBytes=1024**2,backupCount=1)
h.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
h.setFormatter(f)
l.addHandler(h)
del h,f
#hook to log unhandled exceptions
def excepthook(type,value,traceback):
    logging.error("Unhandled exception occured",exc_info=(type,value,traceback))
    #Don't need another copy of traceback on stderr
    if old_excepthook!=sys.__excepthook__:
        old_excepthook(type,value,traceback)
old_excepthook = sys.excepthook
sys.excepthook = excepthook
del excepthook,log_file
# ####################################################
```

There *are* other methods but each has a downside:

- Each logger has an undocumented `<logger>.handlers` list, but it only lists handlers connected to that logger directly. So, you need to iterate over this list for all loggers you have if you have multiple.
- There is a global undocumented `logging._handlerList` (references to all handlers are kept there to shut them down at exit). Likewise, that is an implementation detail.
- Finally, you can override a handler's init logic by

  - replacing `__init__` methods of `Handler` and/or subclass (that will affect everything else that uses `logging`), or by
  - subclassing/[addin a mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098970/are-mixin-class-init-functions-not-automatically-called) to the required classes.

  That is probably an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a number of handlers, you're advised to configure logging using the `logging.config.dictConfig()` API. This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33186558/118903) shows how to configure formatters for handlers; you may be able to adapt it to your needs.